# How can I make the html element always wrap the content?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image]

You see, when the browser width is narrow enough, the scrollbar appears. When I drag the scrollbar to the right, the content exceeds the html element.
Here's the code:

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
lkjlaksjfklajfkalsdddddddaaaadfajflkajflkajflkajflkjasklfjaslkfjaklsjfklasjfklasjfaklsfsd
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `word-break: break-all;` rule to make sure long words don't overflow outside the container:

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
lkjlaksjfklajfkalsdddddddaaaadfajflkajflkajflkajflkjasklfjaslkfjakjfklasjfklasjfaklsfsdasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfadfasdfadsfasd
```

Comment: " width: max-content; " is what I want. Actually, the problem also occurs when html contains a div with a fixed width. Maybe the example I chose didn't accurately convey my intention. Setting html width to "max-content" does the trick.